# Replacing bad date values in python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas which mostly contain correct date values but it also contain bad date values. How can check for those bad date fields and replace it with today's date.

My dataframe will look like

```
Date
12/12/2018
12/11/2018
#REF
12/1/205
12/1/205
N/A
Unknown
6/12/2018
6/3/2018
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can using `to_datetime`

```
pd.to_datetime(df.Date,errors='coerce').fillna(pd.to_datetime('today')).dt.date
Out[484]: 
0    2018-12-12
1    2018-12-11
2    2019-09-29
3    2019-09-29
4    2019-09-29
5    2019-09-29
6    2019-09-29
7    2018-06-12
8    2018-06-03
Name: Date, dtype: object
#df.Date=pd.to_datetime(df.Date,errors='coerce').fillna(pd.to_datetime('today')).dt.date
```